# Temporary DNS by pattern

Tags: dns

I remember a website/DNS that works by pattern. I don't remember the exact rules for the patterns but e.g. `server.1.some.domain` is translated to `server` and `server.2.some.domain` is also translated to `server`. This gives me multiple hostnames for the same machine without registration or changes in `hosts`. What's the name of this website/DNS?

Answer (score 0):

I found it: http://xip.io/

It extracts the IP from the URL ending with `xip.io` and redirects the request to the IP, e.g.  somename.127.0.0.1.xip.io -> 127.0.0.1. Sadly it's not what I described in my question but it's what I remembered.